# How can I list all overloaded cmdlets defined in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

**Context:** One of our teams has a Chocolatey package that calls `Expand-Archive`. However, I have the `pscx` module installed which *also* provides an `Expand-Archive` cmdlet whose parameter signature differs from the built-in cmdlet, and causes this package installation to fail. The solution is to use the module-qualified name in case of such an overload. In the end was able to look at the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1) to get the module name for what it's worth.

Initially, I tried getting the module with:

```
Get-Command Expand-Archive -All
```

but this only listed the cmdlet found in the `pscx` module. It seems that `Get-Command -All` **does not return commands from available modules which have not been loaded yet**. This somewhat makes sense for modules which can't be autoloaded but not the built-in ones like `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive`, and this is concerning as it leaves me unable to audit the available commands in my session without first loading the module.

Once I load the module with one of the following methods:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
```

`Get-Command Expand-Archive -All` indeed shows both definitions in the resolved order, and the module they belong to. This is problematic though, because it inhibits my abililty to audit the commands available on my system, **short of blindly importing all available modules** before running `Get-Command` (which is a problematic solution in its own right).

---

**The ask:** How can I either tell `Get-Command` to *actually* retrieve all resolvable commands available to the session, or obtain this information via other means? As modules are auto-imported based on the first usage of one of its functions (*something* knows the command is in an unloaded module to do the import), I would expect `Get-Command` *should* be able to support this.

Comment: Does `Get-Command Expand-Archive -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive` not work?

Comment: Sure, if I know the name of the module ahead of time. In this case I was trying to find the module the command lives in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all `Export-Archive` commands from among the *available* modules<sup>[1]</sup> (as opposed to those *currently loaded* (imported)):

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable |
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($cmd = $_.ExportedCommands['Expand-Archive']) { $cmd }
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`[System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo) instances output by Get-Module also have command-type-specific `.ExportedAliases`, `.ExportedFunctions`, and `.ExportedCmdlets` properties, as well as `.ExportedVariables`.</sup>

Note:

- If you have *multiple* versions of a module containing such a command installed, the command from each version will be listed separately.
- The output won't tell you which `Export-Archive` command is the *effective* one, i.e. which one will actually be executed if you submit `Export-Archive` as a command; to find the effective one, use `Get-Command Export-Archive`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**[`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) includes commands from *available* modules by default** in principle, but by default only shows the *effective* command by that name.

The **`-All` switch** is meant to show *all* available commands by a given name, even those being *shadowed* by the effective command.

As you've observed, **the use of `-All` unexpectedly limits the candidate pool of module-originating commands to those from modules *currently loaded***, up to at least PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.9.

**Arguably, this is a *bug***, and has been reported in [GitHub issue #16116](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16116)

---

##### Optional `Get-Command` information:

**`Get-Command`'s behavior *without a name (`-Name`) argument*** - whether with or without `-All` - is a bit obscure (albeit mostly documented):

- **Unless you pass a `-Type`(`-CommandType`) argument to explicitly control what command types to report, only the following command types are reported: `Alias`, `Function`, `Filter`, `Cmdlet`**, which notably excludes `ExternalScript` (`*.ps1` script files) and `Application` (external programs).

  - Note: `-Type` accepts *multiple* values, so to find all external scripts and programs, for instance, pass `-Type ExternalScript, Application`
- To report *all* command types, use `-Type All`
- Curiously, not specifying a `-Name` argument seems to apply the `-All` switch, i.e. shadowed commands are *invariably* included.

By contrast, **if a `-Name` argument *is* specified, *all* command types are considered**, and whether or not `-All` is specified *does* make a difference.

- Thus, `Get-Command *` is effectively the same as `Get-Command -Type All`

---

<sup>[1] Those discoverable via the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, i.e. via [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading)</sup>

Comment: To add, `Get-Command -All` does not show external commands. You have to specify `Get-Command -Type Application`. This limitation is not mentioned in the cmdlet documentation for `-All`, either, though it will show all matching commands on the PATH if you give it an external command name.

Comment: Thanks, @BendertheGreatest - I've added this info to the answer, and in the process I've discovered a few additional things - please see my update. In short: it isn't about `-All`, it's about whether a `-Name` argument is passed, and the docs aren't particularly clear on that point.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, what the docs do say is "By default, Get-Command gets all cmdlets, functions, and aliases.", but they don't mention that all types _are_ included once you use a `-Name` argument. `-All` has no bearing on this distinction.